# Firebase analytics events aren't showing

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrate firebase analytics into my project and I can see the events in the android studio logcat and also in firebase debug view and stream view. But when I check the events panel, it doesn't show the event even the default one such as first_open, app_remove, app_update.

This is how I log the event

```
FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.logEvent(
                eventName = AppConstants.EVENT_VIEW_MENU,
                params = bundleOf("category" to "view_tab_menu_${tab?.text.toString()}")
            )

fun logEvent(eventName: String, params: Bundle?) {
    mFirebaseAnalytics?.logEvent(eventName, params)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you  integrate firebase Cloud Messaging close  disable the app measurement part of the Firebase Analytics service

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```